# Handle multiple requests at the same time and update state when one of them is resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I have following scenario:

Multiple http requests will be executed:

```
const sourceOne = http.get(obj1.product_id);
const sourceTwo = http.get(obj2.product_id);
const sourceThree = http.get(obj3.product_id);
const sourceFour = http.get(obj4.product_id);
```

can i somehow using `Promises` or `Observables` to:

1. Execute all of the requests at the same time
2. Update state when one of them is resolved, for example:

- sourceThree, finish first - update state on the client
- sourceFour, complete after sourceThree - update state on the client

All of the possible solutions that i can found are always wait for all of the requests to be completed before updating the state, any ideas?

Comment: You can create a single observable that emits each time o or of the sources emits a value. What do you want emitted, just the most recent item, or an array of all emitted items?

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) to turn multiple observables into a single observable.

```
merge(sourceOne, sourceTwo, sourceThree, sourceFour).subscribe((data) => updateState(data))
```

Here is a link to a stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cg31qz?devToolsHeight=33&file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), it will populate the first promise has been resolved.

> The Promise.race() method returns a promise that fulfills or rejects as soon as one of the promises in an iterable fulfills or rejects, with the value or reason from that promise.

```
const arr [obj1.product_id, obj2.product_id, obj3.product_id, obj4.product_id]

const result = Promise.race(arr.map(i => http.get(i))
```

Comment: Racing promises cancels the one after the first ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have RxJS installed, observables can do that.

All at once

```js
forkJoin([sourceOne, sourceTwo, sourceThree, sourceFour])
  .subscribe(([one, two, three, four]) => {});
```

Update client when one of them resolves :

```js
merge(sourceOne, sourceTwo, sourceThree, sourceFour)
  .subscribe(() => updateUi());
```

Comment: will other continue when one of them is being resolved?

Comment: @AndonMitev forkJoin will wait for all to come at once, and combineLatest will emit everytime one resolves

Comment: @MGX, combineLatest won't work until all of them have emitted at least once.

Comment: @HassanMoin indeed, update my answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is `Promise.race()` which fires, everything in `then()` callback function, after one of the passed promises has been resolved.

```js
const prom1 = new Promise(r => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    r('prom1')
  }, 1200)
})
const prom2 = new Promise(r => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    r('prom2')
  }, 600)
})
const prom3 = new Promise(r => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    r('prom3')
  }, 1000)
})
const prom4 = new Promise(r => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    r('prom4')
  }, 700)
})

Promise.race([prom1, prom2, prom3, prom4]).then(r => {
  console.log(r)
})
```

Comment: Racing promises cancels the one after the first ...

Comment: Yes, race will cancel after the first one is being resolved